# Does Pokemon IV stay same after evolution?

Tags: pokemon-go

For example if I find out my Squirtle has 95% IV, will it stay same percentage after he evolves to Wartortle?

To be clear I'm not talking about CP (Combat power) but IV (Individual Values) which are hidden stats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it does, I've tested this many times on pokemon I've evolved and it is 100% the same.

Source: Personal experience